# Move changes from one source controller into tfs by tfs sdk

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, source-control-explorer

Consider following source controller:

ChangeSet1 : Class Customer { ... }

ChangeSet2 : Class Customer { .. /// }

, ...

I've all versions of Customer.CS file, with their codes.

I've lots of these files in a very old source controller.

Is there any solution to copy these changes & their histories into tfs by tfs sdk?

For example by creating multiple ChangeSets and add files into them and save them.

Finally, I'd like to have a history in tfs & visual studio, as like as normal projects, without losing any history.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which old source control do you have?

Comment: @AdarshShah Thanks for your comment, It's not important, it is a source controller I've developed my self 3 years ago. I've all changes and I can do everything with them by C# codes. I'm going to add them with their histories into tfs by tfs sdk. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I have used TFS integration platform to migrate between different source controls (built-in) and it has worked pretty well for me so far. They have an adapter for file system so check it out and see if you can use that or else you can write a custom adapter as per your needs. I haven't written any custom adapter but looking at the source code and documentation it looks like you can write your own.

Look at the downloads tab after going to below URL to check out the documentation on adapter and look at the IntegrationPlatform/Adapters folder on the source code tab for built-in adapters. I would start by installing the tool and trying it with the file system adapter and then see if you need to write a custom adapter.

Reference Urls:
http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/05/28/tfs-integration-platform-how-do-i-build-my-own-adapter.aspx

Comment: Did you try this? Let me know whether it worked for you or not.